# Completely Remove and Reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I've looked at some of the past answers, but they all seem old/don't seem to currently work in 2016.

I currently have Ubuntu 15.10 installed. I'm looking to completely remove it, and reinstall Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not worried about saving the /home folder. I already have everything I'm interested in saving backed up.

How would I approach this problem

Comment: is it alongside windows ? or is it single os?

Answer (score 1):

From the Live CD you can erase the disk partitions entirely. Then install it and the Installer can arrange all partition for you. I prefer using "Something else" because in the past the Swap wasn't set equally to my ram size in some cases.

To erase the partition search the **Gparted** program and select the disks and choose the disk from the **top right** corner **drop-down menu** :

[image: Step 1]

Then **right-click** the partition you want to erase from the *list* and in this case all partition you would want :

[image: Step 2]

In the end it should look like this :

[image: Last Step]

From there it is  a normal installation via the *Live session*. In the **Unity launcher** click the first launcher that is the **Live installer** and you can install Ubuntu in the wiped disk. In the case you want/need to make the partitions before the *Live installer* you can use either **Gparted** or **Gnome Disks** to do so. `Have fun!`

Answer (score 0):

Boot in with a live CD of Ubuntu(14.04LTS), delete the partitions or use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller (os unisntaller) and reinstall Ubuntu